# How do I enable a chrome extension to show additional search results (similar to what Evernote used to do)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I cannot seem to replicate it now, but in the past, when I used Evernote, when I searched Google in the desktop browser, results that had been saved in Evernote would show up on the search results page as well.

How do I build a Chrome Extension that supports this and are there other illustrative examples?

I searched the Chrome API docs to get my arms around it, but didn't see explicit code that illustrated how to do this.

Comment: To modify web pages you need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). See [the overview](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/architecture-overview/).

Comment: How do I intercept what has been entered into the search bar?

Comment: Use standard DOM events like `change` or `input`.